# How auto-update passbook work?

Tags: iphone, passbook

I'm implementing a solution to generate pass for passbook . I can generate the pass and update it manually via the webServiceURL field and over https.
However, if the pass has the automatic update option checked and if i update a field in the pass, nothing happen. No notification, no update. I don't know why because if i launch an update manually it works.

Comment: Are you generating a push notification?

Answer (score 0):

You have to send a push notification to registered devices, i.e. that has your pass installed (see [Your Server Sends a Push Notification When Something Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW63)), assuming that you have implemented Passbook registration end point (see [Devices Register for Updates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW62) and [Registering a Device to Receive Push Notifications for a Pass](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988-CH0-SW2)